# Please explain the use of 'could' in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Would anyone please explain the use of 'could' in the sentence below?

> We could go to the cinema tomorrow.

Comment: This definitely needs some more context, but going with only what you've got I'd say It indicates a possibility. That sentence could be part of this bigger one: *We could go to the cinema tomorrow or if you want we could go to a restaurant.*

Comment: Thanks, Michael Rybkin. Can I write 'We could go to the cinema tomorrow if we want'?

Comment: @theinlwin yes you could do that...

Answer (score 1):

- We can go tomorrow. ["ability" to do so; are able to]
- We could go tomorrow. [conditional]

could does signify possibility in conditional sentences or in implied conditionals, that is, an implied if clause:

- We could go tomorrow (if you decide to [go]). [present tense after if]
- We could go to the cinema tomorrow if we **want to [go]**.

Don't forget to leave in the **to** when there is a second clause with verbs such as want, wish, hope, like, dislike, etc. (there are lists of these verbs)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and understand, **COULD** is a kind of modal verb and we use it to express if something is possible to do and the past ability to make suggestions and requests.

For example, "Could you please help me with the question if you know how to do it?"

Something like that and you have to remember that ***could** is commonly used in conditional sentences as the conditional form of "can."

**Can you please come forward with adequate information regarding the case?**

Just an example...